# В чем различия понятий: IContext, IDataService, IRepository, IUnitOfWork?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Видел несколько вариантов реализаций этих интерфейсов и не могу понять в чем между ними принципиальные различия. Зачем плодить столько схожих сущностей для одинаковых задач? Может, уже есть классический общепринятый способ организации взаимодействия DataLayer с BusinesLayer применительно к MVVM шаблону? Меня интересует что-то гибкое, подходящее для различных типов источников данных.

Comment: Всё это понятия модельного уровня, и не имеют отношения к WPF (ну и MVVM тоже).

Comment: Уровень бизнес-логики может располагаться либо на уровне M, либо VM. В любом случае, суть в том, что M выставляет возможность работать с собой, как ей кажется правильным, а VM пользуется этой возможностью, как может.

Comment: Так что любое из этих понятий может использоваться с MVVM.

Comment: Согласен, с Вами, что использованные мною теги тут не уместны. А вот по сути понятий я пока не понял для чего их наплодили аж столько? Почему просто не использовать IContext и IDataService.Разве их не достаточно для разделения архитектуры на слои(что нынче в моде)?  .

Comment: Мне кажется, тут играют роль скорее исторические причины. Я, к сожалению, не специалист по базам данных, но мне видится аналогия с набором `Thread`/`ThreadPool`/`BackgroundWorker`/`Task`/`async/await`: они появлялись один за другим, всё лучше и лучше решая проблемы из схожей предметной области. Впрочем, попробую поискать ответ на ваш конкретный вопрос.

Comment: Unit of Work и Repository, настолько я понял, ортогональные понятия. Unit of Work содержит логику того, какие элементы должны быть изменены для данного задания, а Repository — как именно с точки зрения логики базы данных это отобразить в базе.

Comment: Если вы дадите какие-нибудь ссылки на IContext и IDataService, я попробую раскопать информацию и по ним.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смотрите. Repository — это абстракция над базой данных. Данные в таблицах слабо типизированы, связи в них представлены достаточно неудобно, и для их обновления вам нужны в конце-концов SQL-команды, которые представляют код совсем другого проблемного уровня. Обычно для таких случаев не работают прямо, а строят абстракцию над SQL. Абстракцию данных самих таблиц вам предоставляет чаще всего ORM, а уровнем немного выше находится группировка таблиц и «раздача» подходящих имён для операций. Или вы можете не группировать их, и считать объектную модель, предоставляемую ORM, вашим Repository.

Разберём, например, случай блога. Например, ORM может предоставлять вам методы наподобие `IQueryable<Post> Author.GetAllPosts()`. Вы можете построить над этим абстракции `IEnumerable<Post> GetPostsBetween(DateTime start, DateTime end)` или например `IEnumerable<Post> GetPostsWithComments()` или даже `IEnumerable<Post> GetMostDiscussedPosts()`, и это будет ваш Repository.

Хотя, с другой стороны, прятать `IQueryable` и ограничивать себя заранее в возможной логике работы с данными не так уж хорошо, так что возможно вы захотите отказаться от Repository (или сделать его тривиальным — вынести наружу объектную модель ORM и полагаться на силу LINQ). В последнее время этот подход вошёл в моду.

Итак, Repository в том или ином виде позволяет вам абстрагироваться от конкретных особенностей хранения данных. Тем не менее, вы всё ещё обязаны правильно поддерживать связи между данными.

Обратите внимание, что при помощи Repository вы можете хранить ваши данные не только в базе данных, но и в текстовом файле, XML, в чём угодно.

---

[Data Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6cd7c08%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) — это специфический набор классов для ADO.NET (`DbConnection`, `DbCommand`, `DbDataReader`, `DbDataAdapter` и т. д.), которые реализуют более простую, чем Repository, абстракцию над базой данных. Здесь SQL-команды строятся вручную, данные считываются через `DataSet`, а абстракции таблицы в виде коллекции объектов нет. Data Provider абстрагирует свойства и особенности конкретной базы данных, но не прячет от вас специфические для базы данных операции.

Таким образом, эта абстракция является более примитивной альтернативой ORM. Вы можете при этом создать сверху Repository, если хотите, или базировать ваш Unit of Work (см. ниже) прямо на командах, которые предоставляет вам Data Provider.

---

Теперь Unit of Work. Задачи, которые выполняет ваша бизнес-логика, обычно состоят из более чем одного действия. Например, удаление автора может затронуть таблицу с авторами, таблицу с постами, таблицу с комментариями, таблицу с медиафайлами и т. п. Покупка продукта вносит запись в список заказов покупателя и вносит запись в таблицу товаров к отправке. Вам нужно не забыть сделать и то, и другое, поэтому разумно сгруппировать эти действия и дать им имя.

Ещё одна важность группировки — накопление последовательных изменений. Вы можете добавлять продукты в корзину, убирать их, менять их количество, добавлять купоны на скидки, и вносить их в реальную базу данных одним махом (плюс запустить соответствующую логику, следующую за заказом).

Кроме того, вам важно сгруппировать эти вещи и для других целей: чтобы они находились в пределах одной *транзакции*. Итак, эта самая группа и называется Unit of Work. После *выполнения* одного Unit of Work ваши данные будут снова находится в правильном, консистентном состоянии.

Вот хорошая статья об этом, если вы дружите с английским: [The Unit Of Work Pattern And Persistence Ignorance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx).

Ваша бизнес-логика верхнего уровня должна, таким образом, работать не напрямую с Repository/ORM/Data Provider'ом, с этими самыми Unit'ами. Unit of Work — более высокий уровень абстракции, чем Repository, и обычно берёт на себя большую часть работы с ним.

---

По поводу контекста — это очень популярное слово, которое используется в тысяче различных смыслов. Обычно этим словом называются служебные данные, необходимые для проведения разделённой на части работы. (Смотрите ответ @Athari для более подробного объяснения.) Непосредственного отдельного отношения к базам данных понятие «контекст» вроде бы не имеет.

---

В рамках MVVM практически все операции с базой данных принадлежат уровню модели. Unit of Work принадлежит бизнес-логике, которую некоторые относят к уровню VM, а некоторые — тоже к модели. Остальные части (Repository и Data Provider) — чисто модельные конструкции.

Answer (score 3):

`IContext` — это общее понятие, не привязанное к базам данных и хранению сущностей. Контекст — это состояние некоторой среды. Например, если задача может быть прервана и возобновлена, то состояние среды с переменными — "контекст". Если вы запрашиваете у внешней среды по окончании операции вызвать коллбэк и передаёте аргумент, с которым вызвать коллбэк, то аргумент — "контекст". Если у вас безопасная среда выполнения, то набор текущих разрешений и запретов — "контекст". Состояние парсера, хранящее текущие переменные и положение в документе — "контекст".

`IDataService` и `IRepository` — это, вроде, родственные понятия и предполагают операции по хранению некоторых сущностей: получение, создание, обновление, удаление (CRUD). Если код обращается к некоторому внешнему веб-сервису, то его скорее назовут `IDataService`. Если код обращается напрямую к базе данных, то его скорее назовут `IRepository`. Но это вопрос вкуса, и при должной реализации DI оба могут выполнять любую роль и переключать способ хранения в зависимости от любых условий.

`IUnitOfWork` — это способ общения с сервисом для хранения данных из пункта выше. В нём хранятся все операции, которые должны быть применены: добавление, обновление, удаление. По мере выполнения действий пользователем в юнит добавляются произведённые изменения. Затем юнит отправляется в сервис/репозиторий, и последний решает, в какой последовательности применить операции. Это позволяет лучше оптимизировать запросы и удобнее изолировать операции, чем если общаться с сервисом напрямую.

Comment: Уже что то стало проясняться благодаря вашему и VladD ответам. Но возник вопрос: "Затем юнит отправляется в сервис/репозиторий, и последний решает, в какой последовательности применить операции." Что это значит? Я видел реализации репозитария с передачей ему в конструкторе IUnitOfWork и наоборот- в конструктор последнего передается IRepository. Как более правильно? И в основном ссылаются на то, что назначение IUnitOfWork- гарантирование выполнения всех операций в своем IObjectContext, что избавляет от проблем с неопределенностью адресата операций(к примеру несколько источников данных).

Comment: @DmitryB2014: На мой личный вкус, UoW есть абстракция более высокого уровня, чем репозиторий, поэтому UoW должен управлять репозиторием, а не наоборот. Впрочем, это вопрос дизайна программы, а в нём каждый архитектор видит по своему, и вполне может инвертировать зависимости, если ему так больше нравится.